# Seam @Name on entity classes?

Tags: components, entity, seam

I've first seen annotating Seam entity classes here

http://www.developer.com/java/ejb/article.php/10931_3715171_5/Introducing-JBossreg-Seam.htm

and for whatever reason I've been doing so ever since:

```
@Entity
@Table (name= "GADGET")
@Name("gadget")
public class GadgetBean implements Serializable {
   private String mDescription = "";
   private String mType = "";
   ...
}
```

However, I do not use "entity components" like this anywhere in my views. Can anyone explain the use of this and what this gains? Is it a non-practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not using any of these entity components in your views, you should remove the @Name annotation.

Seam is great, but seam components come with overhead in the way of interceptors firing every time you access a method in that class. Since you are not accessing these attributes in your view, there is no need to make them into seam components.  You are incurring the interceptor overhead every time you use a getter or setter from your entity beans.

Seam-gen, the tool used to create seam projects, can also generate entities that are reverse-engineered from your database tables.  By default, the seam-gen entity generator does NOT add the @Name annotation to these classes. That should tell you something!

Hope this helps.